# Get Entity Model from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a stored procedure's return type to match an entity model, this is a simplified version:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerson]
@userId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Perform INSERT statement

    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        People
    WHERE
        PersonId = @result;
END
```

At the moment, this stored procedure is returning an integer according to my EDMX.  However, I want it to return a Person object instead.  How do I go about doing this?  I am using Entity Framework 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO You cannot return a CLR object from sql server. The best you can do is to return the proper string which exactly matches with the entity type in your C# code and use reflection to  create an object.

For example

1. You can have a string something to the following `"NamespaceName.TypeName,AssemblyName"` which will be returned from your sql
2. Then on the c# side you can split it to typename and assemblyname. Then you can pass these to the following method.

```
using System.Reflection;

public static object CreateInstance(string typeName, string assemblyName)
{
    object result = null;

    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName, true, false);

        result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle exception here
    }

    if (result == null)
    {
        //Can handle null here
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course this method assumes that your class has a default constructor. If not then you need to modify the code accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm considering just moving everything over to stored procedures for performance reasons and keeping EF primarily for querying and the entities it provides.